# OpenGL: responding to keyboard issue

Tags: c, opengl, glut

My program reciveves a key from the keyboard. I want the shape to move left/right/up according to pressing the arrows on the keyboard.

This is the relevant part of the code:

```
    case GLUT_KEY_LEFT :
        {
            horizon--;
            glutPostRedisplay();    
            break;

        }
```

However GLUT_KEY_LEFT doesn't respond, but if for example I change it to 'B', than it works.
I have no idea why it doesn't work. The values of GLUT_KEY_LEFT are defined in openGL header file.. Are they wrong?!

Comment: `GLUT_KEY_LEFT` is defined in `<GL/glut.h>`, or `<GLUT/glut.h>` on OS X, not in the OpenGL `gl.h` or `gl3.h` header files. I don't know if that's a possible source of your problem.

Comment: they are defined at glut.h i can see their values: /* directional keys */
#define GLUT_KEY_LEFT   100
#define GLUT_KEY_UP   101
#define GLUT_KEY_RIGHT   102
#define GLUT_KEY_DOWN   103
#define GLUT_KEY_PAGE_UP  104
#define GLUT_KEY_PAGE_DOWN  105
#define GLUT_KEY_HOME   106
#define GLUT_KEY_END   107
#define GLUT_KEY_INSERT   108
#endif

Comment: print the value of the variable you put in your switch, if it's not 100, then it will not reach the case GLUT_KEY_LEFT. Look up what the actual value represents.

Comment: it responds to e,d,f,g... which according to ascii table 100=d 101=e etc.... how do i make it responds to arrows?!

Comment: What function do you use to define a callback for keyboard actions - glutKeyboardFunc?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

May be you define a callback function for keyboard actions using
`glutKeyboardFunc`.

To use `GLUT_KEY_xxx` you should use `glutSpecialFunc` to set a callback.